# How to lock a dreamweaver template

Tags: html, templates, dreamweaver

Hi I am a Webdeign 2 student and I am suppose to make a template from scratch using DreamWeaver CS4. I am having trouble with what I am suppose to do. Heres my code that I have:

```
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Header" -->Header<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<br>
<br>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Body" -->Body<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<br>
<br>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Nav Bar" -->Nav Bar<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<br>
<br>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Text area" -->Text Area<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<br>
<br>
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name='Footer' -->Footer<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
```

My assingment is that I have at least one editable region and at least one locked region.
I don't know how to lock a region could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Hope, that I have understood your Question: you want to create a template for people with HTML-Experience. Some of the lines of code shouldn't be editable, right?

In an HMTL-Document you cannot lock any lines of code. It works like an text document (e.g. .docx). You can change what you want. There is no lock-feature. This does not make also any sense. Learn creating Wordpress-Websites: the most people in the world can not code HTML or anything. They are happy, if they can install any applications ;-)

Maybe this was helpful.

Sincerely Yours
Max

Comment: That's great. My english is not the best ;)